# scss style not getting applied in nx angular workspace lib

Tags: angular, sass, kendo-ui, storybook, nrwl-nx

I have an [NX Workspace for angular](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/getting-started/intro).  All the latest versions (angular 12.0.0, NX 12.3.4, storybook 6.3.0)
I created a lib called ui-core and added a sample nav menu component for testing.
I then added nx storybook schematic and storybook runs and I also have it set up to use tailwind via @ng-neat/tailwind.

I also have a dependency on kendo ui for angular who exposes many scss files for styling their components.

**The problem is** that no matter which way I try to import the styles from ***~@progress/kendo-theme-material*** they do not get applied in the storybook instance.
HOWEVER: They DO get applied if I import the component from the ui-core lib into the main angular app and run ng serve.

EXAMPLE:
right is ng serve of app that uses the menu nav anf left is storybook of same component
[image]

What I have Tried:

1. Change main.js config for storybook (the webPackFinal is the part that was added as per [these docs from storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config)):

```
    const rootMain = require('../../../../.storybook/main');
    const path = require('path');
    
    rootMain.core = {
      ...rootMain.core,
      builder: 'webpack5',
    };
    
    rootMain.exports = {
      ...rootMain.exports,
      webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        });
      },
    };
    
    rootMain.stories.push(
      ...['../src/lib/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/lib/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)']
    );
    
    module.exports = rootMain;
```

2. add import of files to preview.js, also added "css-loader": "^5.2.4", to npm package.json

   `import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/kendo.scss';`

I also tried importing with the following formats in preview.js and it always breaks the storybook build regardless of format:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!~@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../../../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';
```

here is my kendo.scss file:

```
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/appbar/_index.scss";
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/autocomplete/_index.scss";
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/badge/_index.scss";
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/button/_index.scss";
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-material/scss/checkbox/_index.scss";
etc...
```

3. I have tried almost every variation of solution in [this git issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6364)

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out how to get the scss files from kendo ui applied in my storybook instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I need to thank HailToTheKing in the storybook discord for helping with this.

The problem here was that I needed to import the kendo ui modules in to the storybook config for this story.  I did not realize that the modules imported into the nx lib do not get automatically.

So this WAS NOT a scss issue.  The browser console was throwing a lot of element not found errors for the kendo components.  Once I imported them into the storybook config, the component rendered properly.

Here is my component.stories.ts config:

```
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { IndicatorsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-indicators';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { IconsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-icons';
import { NavigationModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-navigation';

export default {
  title: 'Nav Menu',
  component: NavMenuComponent,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<NavMenuComponent> = (args) => ({
  props: args,
  moduleMetadata: {
    imports: [
      LayoutModule,
      InputsModule,
      IconsModule,
      IndicatorsModule,
      NavigationModule,
    ],
  },
});

export const primary = Template.bind({});
primary.args = { title: 'MY APP' };
primary.storyName = 'Top Navigation Menu';
```

Adding the kendo module imports to the moduleMetadata is what made it all work.  This makes sense now because its supposed to be isolated ui testing, haha.

Side note, if you are using angular 12 with storybook 6, at this point you need to use the alpha to get over some build errors.